# Ayuda para realizar proceso de ETL con Yii2 PHP

Tags: php, yii2

¡Hola!

Me veo obligado a solicitar de su ayuda, Después de una larga espera al fin, me toca desarrollar un proceso de ETL (Extraccion, Tranformacion y Carga de los datos) utilizando Yii2

Necesito saber si alguien de la comunidad a desarrollado algún proyecto utilizando Yii2 y le ha aplicado un proceso de ETL (Extraccion, Transformacion y carga de datos). Les agradezco si me pueden enviar documentacion o ejemplos de como realizar un proceso de ETL en Yii2, quedo pendiente de cualquier información que me puedan aportar, es un proyecto academico

Comment: has revisado esta liga https://php-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Si lo revise pero el proceso lo hacen con Laravel

Comment: Puedes crear un comando, y dentro de el realizas el llamado de lo que necesites. La librería solo se instala con composer. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-console.html#create-command

Answer (score 1):

Instala el componente en tu proyecto yii2(utilizando composer `composer require marquine/php-etl`), una vez hecho eso puedes generar un comando(controlador de consola) y dentro de él, en el metodo `init`

Puedes inicializar el uso de `Etl::config($params)`

```
namespace app\commands;

use Marquine\Etl\Etl;
use Marquine\Etl\Job;
use yii\console\Controller;

class EtlController extends Controller
{
    public $file;
    public function init()
    {
        Etl::config([
            'path' => '/path/to/etl/files',
            'database' => [
                // Base de datos a utilizar
                'default' => 'sqlite',

                'connections' => [

                    'sqlite' => [
                        'driver' => 'sqlite',
                        'database' => '/path/to/database.sqlite',
                    ],

                    'mysql' => [
                        'driver' => 'mysql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '3306',
                        'database' => 'dbname',
                        'username' => 'user',
                        'password' => 'pass',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
                    ],

                    'pgsql' => [
                        'driver' => 'pgsql',
                        'host' => 'localhost',
                        'port' => '5432',
                        'database' => 'dbname',
                        'username' => 'user',
                        'password' => 'pass',
                        'charset' => 'utf8',
                        'schema' => 'public',
                    ],

                ],

            ],

        ]);
    }
    public function options($actionID)
    {
        return ['file'];
    }

    public function optionAliases()
    {
        return ['f' => 'file'];
    }

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        // ejecución de la tarea de etl
        Job::start()
        // datos a extraer
        ->extract('table', 'nombre_tabla_extraer', [
            'connection' => 'mysql' // Base de datos de donde obtendre los datos, si no viene seteado se utiliza el valor que tiene el campo 'default'
        ]) 
        // transformacion a aplicar a los datos
        ->transform('trim', ['columns' => ['name', 'email']])
        // donde cargare los datos
        ->load('table', 'users', [
            'connection' => 'pgsql' // Base de datos a donde voy a insertar los datos
        ]);
    }
}
```

extractores de datos
https://php-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extractors/#table

transformadores de datos
https://php-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/transformers/

cargadores de datos
https://php-etl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/loaders/

en consola lo llamas como 
`./yii etl`

Comment: No entiendo la base de datos a utilizar, el proceso de ETL se realiza de la siguiente manera tengo una base de datos de la cual voy a extraer unos datos los transformo y luego los cargo en otra en esa caso cual seria la base de datos a extraer y cual seria la que voy a cargar

Comment: en dado caso puedes utilizar el extractor de la base de datos, lo coloco en un momento

Comment: No entiendo lo de generar un comando (controlador de consola)

Comment: Creas un Controlador en tu carpeta commads, como cualquier controlador que utilizas para la web, solo extiende del controlador `yii\console\Controller` y lo mandas a llamar desde la consola o terminal `./yii etl`

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no te queda claro? no estoy seguro si continuamos hablando de poder abrir un chat mediante esta plataforma.

Comment: Es mejor abrir un chat tengo varias dudas

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73976/discussion-between-hammerffall-bk-and-sebastian-salazar).